# How can I show the file size of a downloaded file in Firefox in the little dropdown view?

Tags: firefox

- Firefox version: 54.0-1
- Linux: 4.11.6-3-ARCH

Ever since Firefox's version 54 (or was it 53?) came out, the dropdown window of the download arrow only shows "finished" (or whatever exactly it says in your locale) after a download has finished. It used to show the file size of the corresponding entry.

Is it possible to bring that piece of information (the size of the downloaded file) back?

Answer (score 0):

On Firefox 56.0b5 (on Windows), I can see the file sizes of completed downloads from the downloads bubble. I tested this with both externally-downloaded files and with devtools snapshots.

[image: Downloads toolbar bubble]

In the event that this still isn't looking right for you, there's always the slightly more labor-intensive option of clicking the Show All Downloads button, which should show your full download history in even more detail (you can see the date/time and domain name too).

[image: Downloads window]

If you still don't see what you need to see, can you verify that there are no themes or addons installed that are modifying your UI? Try a fresh FF profile too. If you still don't have any luck, it might be time to compare stable with beta/nightly or file a Bugzilla report!